# PHP/HTML return all rows from Oracle Database Query

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display multiple rows of data from a SQL query. I was able to build the reference so that table currently shows one row but was wondering how to show all rows using the same table structure.

```
 <?php
    include('connect.php');
    oci_execute($sql);    
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array ($sql)) {
        $pt  = $row[0]; 
        $eas = $row[1]; 
        $shd = $row[2]; 
        $epc = $row[3]; 
        $tpc = $row[4]; 
        $uid = $row[5]; 
    }
?>
```

Using the table structure below

```
<table class="table" id="aut">
    <tr>
         <th>Pt</th>
         <th>Eas</th>
         <th>Cs</th>
         <th>Or</th>
         <th>Pr</th>
         <th>Ct?</th>
         <th>Al</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="Pt" value="<?php echo $pt; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Eas" value="<?php echo $eas; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Cs" value="<?php echo $tpc; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Or" value="<?php echo $shd; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Pr" value="<?php echo $usd; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Al" value="<?php echo $epc; ?>" class="form-control" disabled></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be something like this:

```
<table class="table" id="aut">
        <tr>
             <th>Pt</th>
             <th>Eas</th>
             <th>Cs</th>
             <th>Or</th>
             <th>Pr</th>
             <th>Ct?</th>
             <th>Al</th>
        </tr>
<?php

    include('connect.php');

    oci_execute($sql);    

    while ($row = oci_fetch_array ($sql)) {

    $pt     = $row[0]; 
    $eas   = $row[1]; 
    $shd   = $row[2]; 
    $epc    = $row[3]; 
    $tpc    = $row[4]; 
    $uid   = $row[5]; 

?>


    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="Pt" value="<?php echo $pt; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Eas" value="<?php echo $eas; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Cs" value="<?php echo $tpc; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Or" value="<?php echo $shd; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Pr" value="<?php echo $usd; ?>" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Al" value="<?php echo $epc; ?>" class="form-control" disabled></td>
    </tr>

<?php

}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked to get the reamining rows from the query Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a lot of optimization, if you use DB calls and output in the same file, it's always wiser to put the output in a variable and only then echo the end result something like this:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
oci_execute($sql);

$table = '<table class="table" id="aut">
    <tr>
        <th>Pt</th>
        <th>Eas</th>
        <th>Cs</th>
        <th>Or</th>
        <th>Pr</th>
        <th>Ct?</th>
        <th>Al</th>
    </tr>';

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $table .= '<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="Pt" value="' . $row[0] . '" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Eas" value="' . $row[1] . '" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Cs" value="' . $row[2] . '" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Or" value="' . $row[3] . '" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Pr" value="' . $row[4] . '" class="form-control" readonly=""></td>
    <td><!-- What happened to Ct? --></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Al" value="' . $row[5] . '" class="form-control" disabled></td>
</tr>';

}

$table = '</table>';

echo $table;
```